# Redirecionamento htaccess Mobile

Tags: php, htaccess

Queria fazer um redirecionamento do site desktop para o site mobile usando o htaccess. Eu já consegui fazer, porém eu queria passar a url do desktop para a url do mobile para eu poder tralhar a conversão.

Ex:

www.sitedesktop.com.br/#/categorias/informatica/pagina/3/

queria fazer com que o htaccess redirecionasse pro mobile passando os parametros depois do #/. A index do mobile terá uma variável para receber esse parâmetro.

O real problema é, converter a url do desktop para url do mobile, uma vez que as duas são diferentes. Eu só preciso receber no mobile a url que o cliente acessou pelo desktop para poder fazer o tratamento disso. Se houver outro caminho. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um script do htaccess para redirecionamento mobile.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Checka se esta é uma string de consulta noredirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Seta o cookie, e pula para a próxima regra
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.website.com]

# Verifica se isso é um dispositivo móvel
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Verifica se ainda não estamos em um site mobile.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Não consigo ler e escrever cookies no mesmo pedido, deve duplicar a condição
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Certifique-se de que não criamos o cookie antes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Agora, redirecione para o site móvel
RewriteRule ^ http://m.website.com [R,L]
```

Fonte: [Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess)